# SSH authentication breaks overnight

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, ssh-keys

I'm running a VM instance with node installed and only 3 .js files and the config and package .json files, and for some reason SSH authentication stops working the next day even when working completely fine the day prior. Setting a new SSH key doesn't work, since it will refuse to accept any at all. I always get the following error:

`SSH Authentication has failed. In order to debug, please analyze the /var/log/auth.log file on the target machine using the serial console. Reading the recent serial port output may also be helpful.`

The only way I've found to fix this is make a new VM instance and start over again, but I already had to do that once. I'm definitely not about to delete and remake the same instance every day I need it.

- Tried using new SSH keys, same error occurs.
- Tried clicking the "troubleshoot" button in SSH-in-browser. VM and network status will return "OK", but user permissions will infinitely load.
- Tried making a new instance in case this one somehow corrupted itself. If I return to it the next day the same SSH issue occurs rendering the VM unusable.

Comment: Double-check if the VM's IP address changed. Google supports static IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud also offers to connect to VMs using serial console for Linux please refer to https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-using-serial-console
as you are not able to connect via IP now..
The Linux OS will be showing errors on the Serial Console while boot that can help you diagnose the bug .. as my past experience this also happens when the VM storage is full, further how you can use serial console to check this out exactly.